# How do I make a minimal Ubuntu installation?

Tags: installation

I need a system that has only basic system commands, the minimum required drivers (network, screen, etc ...), apt and python!

It's for a project for a robot.

Comment: There are specialized distros that will be much better suited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the Alternate CD (text-based installer):

#### Minimal command-line installation

1. On boot, select the language.
2. This will show the boot screen; press <kbd>F4</kbd> and use the arrow keys to select the "Install a command-line system" option:

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to begin installation and follow all the steps.

#### Customized minimal installation

1. 1. On boot, select the language.
2. This will show the boot screen; press <kbd>F6</kbd> and use the arrow keys to mark the "Expert Mode" option:

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to begin installation and follow all the steps. After the base system is installed, you will have the option to install the Ubuntu Desktop or manually use `aptitude` to select custom packages you want to install.

Answer (score 3):

Try the Ubuntu '[Minimal Installation CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD/)'. It requires a network connection to download packages at installation CD though.